# How to read firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I list all documents in a firestore

[image]

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('groups')
                      .doc('dialog')
                      .get()
                      .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                      print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
                    } else {
                      print('Document does not exist on the database');
                    }
                  });
```

this code Always return to else

Comment: The document you're requesting (groups/dialog) doesn't exist.  You can tell because its name is in italics.  It has nested subcollections, but those will not come back in a query.  You have to query those separately.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data):

> When you delete a document, Cloud Firestore does not automatically delete the documents within its subcollections. You can still access the subcollection documents by reference. For example, you can access the document at path `/mycoll/mydoc/mysubcoll/mysubdoc` even if you delete the ancestor document at `/mycoll/mydoc`.

Non-existent ancestor documents [appear in the console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#non-existent_ancestor_documents), but they do not appear in query results and snapshots.

---

> A document can exist even if one or more its ancestors don't exist. For example, the document at path `/mycoll/mydoc/mysubcoll/mysubdoc` can exist even if the ancestor document `/mycoll/mydoc` does not. The Cloud Firestore data viewer displays non-existent ancestor document as follows:

- In a collection's list of documents, the document IDs of non-existent ancestor documents are **italicized**.
- In a non-existent ancestor document's information panel, the data viewer points out that the document does not exist.

---

Since your document name is italicized, which means you either deleted the document or added the subcollection to an empty document which it seems you might have done according to your screenshot. Therefore to solve the issue delete the collection `group` and add the document with data:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
db.collection("group").doc("dialog").set({"name" : "peter"}).then((value){
  db.collection("group").doc("dialog").collection("Tkxij").add({"test" :"test"});
});
```

Also queries are shallow, meaning if you are referencing a document then you will only get the data of that document, you won't get the data inside the subcollections.

Comment: There are alredy data in collection("Tkxij")

Comment: The document dialog is empty and then you added a subcollection to it, try the code that i gave you

Comment: @harsha.kuruwita did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the code for your problem hope this clears your doubt, feel free to ask if you have any doubt.

```
getData( ) async{

    final collectionData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups').get();

    //this forEach method will give every document of that collection
     collectionData.docs.forEach((doc) {
       final docData = doc.data();
       final fieldData = docData['fieldName'];
     });

  }
```